# MouseEnter event does not fire when entering parent from child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom-events

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I attach mouseenter and mouseout events like so:

```
$("*").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
});

$("*").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
});
```

Now, imagine the following mouse sequence of events:

1. I move the mouse into the parent div. As expected the mouseenter event fires and the mouse_over class is put on the parent.
2. I move into one of the children. The mouseout event fires for the parent, and the mouseenter event fires for the child. Good.
3. I move the mouse back into the parent. The mouseenter DOES NOT fire here.

The third step is the issue here. I want the mouse_over class to be put back on the parent when reentering the parent from its child element.

I think I understand why this is happening, as technically my mouse is in the parent the whole time so firing the mouseenter event does not make sense.

Here's a fiddle better illustrating what I'm trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/tg1wg1xx/

If you hover into the parent and children elements, you'll notice on your way out the pattern overlay is not placed on the parent.

So how can I ensure that the overlay is always placed on whatever element I am currently hovering over?

Comment: Is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/tg1wg1xx/7/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Boris explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745616/2324107), there's 2 different events. To quote him :

> - `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are triggered when you enter and leave a hierarchy of nodes, but not when you navigate that hierarchy's descendance.
> - `mouseover` and `mouseout` are triggered when the mouse respectively enters and leaves a node's "exclusive" space, so you get a "out" when the mouse gets into a child node.

That being said, you need `mouseover` and `mouseout` since you need to trigger the mouse out when hovering a child.

```
$("*").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
});

$("*").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
});
```

Next, you need to know that event bubble in the tree. So when you `mouseover` on a child, the event is also propagated to the parents. That's why the parent is in hover state even when hovering a child.

To solve that, you need to use `.stopPropagation()` on the event object.

```
$("*").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("*").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

## [See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/tg1wg1xx/7/)

---

## Bonus

In the spirit of writing less code, you can also use that :

```
$("*").on("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("mouse_over");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

mouse events in javascript can be disorienting. Please note that there are two pairs of events that don't mean the same thing :

- `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are triggered when you enter and leave a hierarchy of nodes, but not when you navigate that hierarchy's descendance.
- `mouseover` and `mouseout` are triggered when the mouse respectively enters and leaves a node's "exclusive" space, so you get a "out" when the mouse gets into a child node.

the behavior you are observing is because you are mixing the two : I updated your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/drxrea7e/1/ to use enter and leave.

you can refer to the events' [documentation on mozilla's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout#See_also) for detailed info.

Edit after your comment: ah then we need another thing :

the event actually bubbles, so the parent also receives it (but with target = theChild). So you want to add the class only if event.target == this :see my new version of the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/drxrea7e/3/.

The children get the image from the class .mouse_over AND the red color from .parent, because background:url() overwrites background-color:white. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Wow, I've been doing web development for many years and never knew that there were two different events so thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately, your fiddle is still not doing exactly what I want. In your fiddle, when you hover into a child element, the parent remains "highlighted". I would like for JUST  the child element to be highlighted in that situation. I am going to read the docs for the events and see if I can figure out a solution, but thank you for pointing out my naivety.

Comment: heh, for the record I do think the names are very confusing, so not naivety so much :). please see my edit about bubbling. stopPropagation() would also work, but I don't like it as it may break other behaviors up-and down- the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Made some updates in your code to make it work as you wanted.

```js
$("*").on("mouseover", function(e) {
 $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("*").on("mouseout", function(e) {
 $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#parent {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color:red;
}

.child {
  padding: 6px;
  background-color:white;
}

.mouse_over {
    background:url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAIUlEQVQYV2NkYGBIY2BgmMUABYxQGi4IEwCJgwWRBcCCAHscA2vMYjzKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
    ) repeat !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Binod, this does indeed do what I want so thank you. However, Karl provided a solution first in the comment so I'm going to give him some time to add a response himself. But once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: That's fine @thatidiotguy. You can actually ask him to post his answer,